# Prove that $f(x) = \frac{x}{\log_2(1+x)}$ is a concave function, where x>0.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, logarithms

Who can tell me how to prove that $f(x) = \frac{x}{\log_2(1+x)}$ is concave?  Thanks a lot in advance.

Take the second derivative:
$f^{''}(x) = \frac{-\ln2*(x+2)*\big(\log_2(1+x)\big)^2+2x\log_2(1+x)}{\big(\ln2*(1+x)\log_2(1+x))^2\big)^2}$.

How to decide the second derivative is a negative value?

Comment: no one unless you show what you have tried..

Comment: I have spent about 5 hours to do it. But I still can not solve it.

Comment: what is a problem? Take the second derivative.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write your questions. To get better answers, walk us through your thought process. What have you tried so far? What do you think you should do?

Comment: Take the second derivative and show it is negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second derivative,
ignoring the $_2$
which doesn't matter,
is
$\dfrac{2 x - (x + 2) \ln(1 + x)}{(1 + x)^2 \ln^3(1 + x)}
$
so we want to show that
$g(x)
=2 x - (x + 2) \ln(1 + x)
\lt 0$.

$g(0) = 0$.
$g(1)
=2-3\ln(2)
\approx -.08
$,
$g'(x)
=2-\ln(1+x)-\dfrac{x+2}{1+x}
=-\ln(1+x)+\dfrac{2+2x-(x+2)}{1+x}
=-\ln(1+x)+\dfrac{x}{1+x}
$
but
$\ln(1+x)
=\int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{1+t}
\ge\int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{1+x}
=\dfrac{x}{1+x}
$
so
$g'(x) \le 0$
and,
for large $x$,
$\ln(1+x)
\gt 2
$
for
$x > e^2-1
$
so
$g(x)
\lt 2x-2(x+2)
=-4
$
for $x > e^2-1$.

Therefore
$g(x) < 0$
for $x > 0$
and the function
is concave.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks a lot for your help.